# Array indices in Mathematica

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica

I have just begin with Mathematica and am having a small problem. I have large polynomial expressions containing coefficients like `A[1,1],B[2,1]` which have to be integrated. The problem is that after integration the expressions containing coefficients like `A[1,1], B[1,2]` etc are being displayed as `A[1.,1.] ,B[1.,2.]`. Why are these dots appearing in the problem?? This is affecting the rest of my programs execution. This is what the output looks like:

```
Cos Projection(1,0)
31.3545 A[1.,0.][t]-1.76595 A[1.,1.][t]^2+76.5283 A[1.,0.][t] A[1.,1.][t]^2+57.4837 A[1.,1.][t]^2 A[1.,2.][t]-5.36733 A[1.,2.][t]^2+76.8287 A[1.,0.][t] A[1.,2.][t]^2-1.76595 B[1.,1.][t]^2+76.5283 A[1.,0.][t] B[1.,1.][t]^2-57.4837 A[1.,2.][t] B[1.,1.][t]^2+114.967 A[1.,1.][t] B[1.,1.][t] B[1.,2.][t]-5.36733 B[1.,2.][t]^2+76.8287 A[1.,0.][t] B[1.,2.][t]^2+3.14159 (A[1.,0.]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]
```

Comment: In Mathematica, `A[1, 1]` world be a function call. Array indices are written as `A[[1, 1]]`.

Comment: I'd like to see the input that generated this output.

Comment: Sounds like you may have applied `N[]` along the way somewhere.  Is that the case?  `Integrate` will not convert 1 to 1.0 here (and `NIntegrate` won't work if you have anything symbolic in your expression).  If it does for you, can you post a short example where this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try giving `A` and `B` the `NHoldAll` attribute:

```
In[1]:= N[A[1,2]]    

Out[1]= A[1., 2.]

In[2]:= SetAttributes[A, NHoldAll];

In[3]:= N[A[1,2]]

Out[3]= A[1, 2]
```

Comment: @Harmeet: If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it by pressing the check mark symbol on the left.